# Android: After using a custom action bar, no action bar shown in another activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have one question about custom action bar
I have two activities, and both activities are AppCompatActivity
In the first activity, I created a custom action bar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.custom_actionbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

When I start the second activity, it doesn't display the action bar.
Should I repeat the above code for the second activity to display action bar? Or is there a way to display action bar?

Comment: Yes you have to add action bar to each activity.

Comment: add toolbar in both of your xml. and get in both activity

Comment: I think for custom actionbar yoy need to repeate your code for second activity. There is no way to make it for whole application.

Comment: You can use 1 Activity and load Fragment as a content. So, you'll just config action bar one time.

Comment: post xml code of both activities......

Comment: you can create a `BaseActivity` that extends `AppCompatActivity`, create your `ActionBar` in that `Activity` and extend that `BaseActivity` in both the `Activities`, this way you will not have to repeat the code...